# Uploading multiple apk in google play

Tags: android, google-play, multiple-apk, android-multiple-apk

I was uploading two apks - one for devices with api >=9 and <18 and the other one >=18. When I download app from android 5.0 there is no problem, but when I try download app from android 4.4.1 Google Play show message: "Your device is not consisted with this version"

Here is printscreen from my google play developers console:

[image]

What do I do wrong? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why you want to upload two APK files for different versions?

Comment: My app is connected with estimote beacons. The estimote sdk require API>18, but I want my app works on older devices, but without estimote library and sdk.

Comment: But you can control it programmatically If the device is lower then 18,then you need not to use library.

Comment: @NigamPatro said right dear  control it pragmatically

Comment: how? if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
  // use your library here
} - this solution is not working